# Showing $\bar{A} = <A>$ where $<A>$ is the smallest subgroup of G containg $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to show the following

First define 
\begin{align}
<A> : = \cap_{A \subseteq H, H\leq G} H
\end{align}
$i.e$, $<A>$ is the smallest subgroup of G containing $A$.

and define 
\begin{align}
\bar{A} := \{ a_1^{\epsilon_1} \cdots a_n^{\epsilon_n} | n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, a_i \in A, \epsilon_{i} = \pm 1, \forall i \in \{1, 2, \cdots n-1\} \}
\end{align}

And what i want to show is two definition are equivalent $i.e$, 
\begin{align}
<A> = \bar{A}
\end{align}

The textbook (Dummit) proves this by $\bar{A} \subseteq <A>$ and $ <A> \subseteq \bar{A}$

(i) First, since each $a \in A$ may be written as $a^1$, it follows $A \subseteq \bar{A}$ hence $<A> \subseteq \bar{A}$.

But i can accept the first part $A \subseteq \bar{A}$ but i don't understand the logic of $<A> \subseteq \bar{A}$.

(ii) For the reverse part $i.e$, $\bar{A} \subseteq <A>$, i understand the logic.

how  $A \subseteq \bar{A}$ implies $<A> \subseteq \bar{A}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\langle A\rangle$ is the intersection of *all subgroups that contain $A$*. So, in order to show that $\langle A\rangle \subset\overline{A}$, it is enough to notice that $A\subset\overline{A}$ and $\overline{A}\leq G$.

In fact, since an element $a\in\langle A\rangle$ also belongs to any subgroup that contains $A$, it follows that $a\in \overline{A}$.

EDIT: It may be easier if we write $\langle A\rangle=\bigcap_{H\in\mathcal{S}}H$, where $\mathcal{S}:=\{H\leq G:A\subset H\}$. Now, notice that, by definition, $\langle A\rangle \subset H$ for any $H\in\mathcal{S}$, because $x\in\bigcap_{H\in\mathcal{S}}H$ if and only if $x\in H$ for all $H\in\mathcal{S}$. Since $\overline{A}\in\mathcal{S}$, it follows that $\langle A\rangle \subset \overline{A}$.

Comment: I am not sure for your statement of "enough to notice". I notice that $A\subset \bar{A}$ and $\bar{A} \leq G$ via subgroup test. Why it is enough to notice? In my first guess the definition of <A> implies $A \subset <A>$. am i right?

Comment: Maneli Mezabraba: At least $<A>$ has an element of $A$, maximally it can be group $G$ itself, when $H=G$

Comment: I put my comments into the answer. Please, let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\subseteq$ $\bar{A}$, minimality of $<A>$ implies that any other subgroup containing $A$ is contained in $<A>$, i.e., $\bar{A} \subseteq <A>$

Comment: Actually, minimality of $\langle A\rangle$ implies that $\langle A\rangle$ is _minimal_, so $\langle A\rangle\subset B$ for any $B\leq G$ s.t. $A\subset B$.