# If $A$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $\langle A\rangle=A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is related with my former question [Showing $\bar{A} = <A>$ where $<A>$ is the smallest subgroup of G containg $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208668/showing-bara-a-where-a-is-the-smallest-subgroup-of-g-containg-a)

For this problem, extend $A$ be a subgroup of $G$,  deduece 
$\langle A\rangle=A$.

Here is my trial

I want to prove this by

$A \subseteq \langle A\rangle$ and $\langle A\rangle \subseteq A$

First one can be read off from definition

The usual defintion of $\langle A\rangle$ is for $A$ be any subset of G 
\begin{align}
\langle A\rangle : = \bigcap_{A \subseteq H, H\leq G} H
\end{align}
reading of from defintion i can see $ A \subseteq \langle A\rangle$,

Now i am being a trouble of showing the second one. $\langle A\rangle \subseteq A$.

Is there any idea?

Comment: Hint: Is $A$ one of the elements of the intersection?

Comment: What do you mean by "extend $A$ to be a subgroup of $G$"?

Comment: @Couchy311, the usual definition $<A>$ is $A$ be any subset of $G$, For above problem $A$ be a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Anyway, i solved this problem. Since $A$ is a subgroup, element of $<A>$ is in $A$. a subset condition does not guarantee that the element of $<A>$ is in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that $A$ is actually a subgroup, then $A$ appears as one on the $H$'s in your big intersection above. Hence $\langle A \rangle \subseteq A$.